# Use performSelector:withObject: afterDelay: inside UIButton action

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am using the  `[performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01]` inside IBAction of a UIButton, the reloadData method draw some subviews on the main view in a particular way, the issue is when I tap the button quickly and repeatedly the selector "ReloadData" executed multiple times, event though I am canceling the all previous requests to that selector, and this results in duplication for the subviews in the main view

```
-(IBAction) myButtonIsTapped
{
     [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(reloadData) object:nil];

    [self performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];

}
```

and reload data method like the following:

```
-(void) reloadData
{
     @synchronized(self){
        // clear all subviews from the main view
        // draw new subviews
     }
}
```

Comment: how do you know the view is being duplicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
-(IBAction) myButtonIsTapped
{
    [self.myButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    [self performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];

}

-(void) reloadData
{
    // Long task...
    // Enable the button again:
    [self.myButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

}
```

Sometimes is just easier to control what the user is doing (UI), than logically dealing with what he has done.

Comment: if I tap the button While the userInteraction is disabled, then the button action executed after the userInteraction become enabled, Why this happens?

Comment: The point is that after what you want to do is done, you should enable the button again.

Answer (score 0):

Do one Thing create one `BOOL variable` and set in `viewdidload` yes and check in function if it is yes then method call and also make it no in buttonmake method.